# combine multiple legacy ASCII .vtk files into a single file using python-vtk

Tags: python, vtk

during my calculation I save a bunch of .vtk files which are related to a single time step. Every file describes a polyhedron (a C++ class I have defined) using the POLYDATA ASCII file format. The polyhedrons get written by a simple member function of the polyhedron class.

In order to avoid defining a completely new class for the polyhedron collection that I need to visualize and messing up my C++ code, I want to combine multiple .vtk files into a single .vtk file.

Using python-vtk causes me some problems:

```
from vtk import * 

reader = vtkPolyDataReader()
reader.SetFileName("file1.vtk")

reader.Update()
polyData1 = reader.GetOutput()

reader.SetFileName('file2.vtk')

reader.Update()
polyData2 = reader.GetOutput()


# Expand the output points

points1 = polyData1.GetPoints()

points2 = polyData2.GetPoints()

insertPosition = points1.GetNumberOfPoints()

for i in xrange(points2.GetNumberOfPoints()):
    insertPoint = points2.GetPoint(i)
    points1.InsertPoint(insertPosition, 
                        insertPoint[0], insertPoint[1], insertPoint[2])
    insertPosition += 1

print points1.GetNumberOfPoints()

# Change the cell ids of every cell in the polydata2 to correspond with 
# the new points (appended point array)

increment = points1.GetNumberOfPoints();

for i in xrange(polyData2.GetNumberOfCells()):
    cell  = polyData2.GetCell(i)
    cellIds = cell.GetPointIds()
    for j in xrange(cellIds.GetNumberOfIds()):
        oldId = cellIds.GetId(j)
        cellIds.SetId(j, oldId + increment)


polyData1.Allocate(polyData1.GetNumberOfCells(), 1)

for i in xrange(polyData2.GetNumberOfCells()):
    cell = polyData2.GetCell(i)
    polyData1.InsertNextCell(cell.GetCellType(), cell.GetPointIds())


writer = vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName("output.vtk")
writer.SetInput(polyData1)
writer.Write()
```

By doing this I will have duplicate points, and that's o.k. The problem is that this script executed on the following .vtk files:

file1:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
surface written 2011-12-19T15:30:18
ASCII

DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 8 float
0.48999999999999999112 0.4000000000000000222 0.5999999999999999778
0.48999999999999999112 0.5 0.5999999999999999778
0.48999999999999999112 0.5 0.69999999999999995559
0.48999999999999999112 0.4000000000000000222 0.69999999999999995559
0.5 0.5 0.5999999999999999778
0.5 0.5 0.69999999999999995559
0.5 0.4000000000000000222 0.69999999999999995559
0.5 0.4000000000000000222 0.5999999999999999778

POLYGONS 6 30
4 0 1 2 3 
4 4 5 6 7 
4 4 1 2 5 
4 6 5 2 3 
4 7 0 1 4 
4 0 7 6 3 

CELL_DATA 6
FIELD attributes 1
zone 1 6 float
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

file2:

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
surface written 2011-12-19T15:30:18
ASCII

DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 8 float
0.58999999999999996891 0.5999999999999999778 0.5
0.58999999999999996891 0.69999999999999995559 0.5
0.58999999999999996891 0.69999999999999995559 0.5999999999999999778
0.58999999999999996891 0.5999999999999999778 0.5999999999999999778
0.5999999999999999778 0.69999999999999995559 0.5
0.5999999999999999778 0.69999999999999995559 0.5999999999999999778
0.5999999999999999778 0.5999999999999999778 0.5999999999999999778
0.5999999999999999778 0.5999999999999999778 0.5

POLYGONS 6 30
4 0 1 2 3 
4 4 5 6 7 
4 4 1 2 5 
4 6 5 2 3 
4 7 0 1 4 
4 0 7 6 3 

CELL_DATA 6
FIELD attributes 1
zone 1 6 float
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Results in points having like 8 coordinates and cells (faces) that are not added at all.

Is it just me or do the python wrappers for vtkArray and similar vtkObjects do not have the option to be iterated over?

Answer (score 3):

You should consider using the [vtkAppendPolyData](http://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkAppendPolyData.html) to merge the files.

```
from vtk import * 

reader = vtkPolyDataReader()
append = vtkAppendPolyData()

filenames = ['file1.vtk', 'file2.vtk']
for file in filenames:
    reader.SetFileName(file)
    reader.Update()
    polydata = vtkPolyData()
    polydata.ShallowCopy(reader.GetOutput())
    append.AddInputData(polydata)

append.Update()    

writer = vtkPolyDataWriter()
writer.SetFileName('output.vtk')
writer.SetInput(append.GetOutput())
writer.Write()
```

Also, note that calling the reader a second time will overwrite the output dataset from the first input file with the second input file. You must do a ShallowCopy (as in the script above) if you want to use the same reader.

Answer (score 2):

I gave up the python-vtk api for this purpose, here's a tiny fast written class that does the job, someone may find it helpful:

```
class polyDataVtk(object):
    """Class representing the polydata vtk information stored in legacy ASCII .vtk POLYDATA files."""
    def __init__(self, fileName = None):
        self.__points = []
        self.__polygons = []
        if fileName is not None:
            self.__fileName = fileName 

    def parse(self, fileName):
        """Parse the POLYDATA information from a .vtk file and append the data to the object.
           Does not check for the file consistency."""
        file = open(fileName, 'r')

        # Use local data first. 
        points = []
        polygons = []

        line = ""
        while(True):
            line = file.readline()
            if 'POINTS' in line:
                break

        nPoints = 0

        if (line == ""):
            print "No POINTS defined in the .vtk file"
            return

        # Set the number of points
        nPoints = int(line.split()[1])

        # Append the numbers.
        for i in xrange(nPoints):
            points.append(map(lambda x : float(x), file.readline().split()))

        # Append polygons.
        line = ""

        while(True):
            line = file.readline()
            if 'POLYGONS' in line:
                break
        if (line == ""):
            print "No POLYGONS defined in the .vtk file"
            return
        # Set the number of polygons.
        nPolygons = int(line.split()[1])

        # Read the polygons.
        for i in xrange(nPolygons):
            line = file.readline()
            polygons.append(map(lambda x : int(x) + len(self.__points), line.split())[1:])

        # File parsed without a problem.
        self.__points.extend(points)
        self.__polygons.extend(polygons)
        file.close()

    def write(self,fileName=None, append=False):
        # Overwrite the filename provided to the constructor.
        if fileName is not None:
            self.__fileName = fileName

        # No fileName is provided by the constructor or the write method.
        if self.__fileName is None:
            self.__fileName = "result.vtk"

        # Append or overwrite?
        if append:
            file = open(self.__fileName, 'a')
        else:
            file = open(self.__fileName, 'w')

        file.writelines("# vtk DataFile Version 2.0\n")
        file.writelines("appended vtk files\n")
        file.writelines("ASCII\n")
        file.writelines("DATASET POLYDATA\n")

        file.writelines("POINTS %d float \n" % len(self.__points))

        for point in self.__points:
            file.writelines("%.10f %.10f %.10f\n" % (point[0], point[1], point[2]))

        size = 0
        for polygon in self.__polygons:
            size += len(polygon)
        file.writelines("POLYGONS %d %d \n" % (len(self.__polygons), 
                                               size 
                                             + len(self.__polygons)))

        for polygon in self.__polygons:
            file.writelines("%d " % len(polygon))
            for label in polygon:
                # I don't know how many labels are there in general.
                file.writelines("%d " % label)
            file.writelines("\n")

        file.close()

    def fileName(self):
        return self.__fileName
```